# PGI compiler: compile-time error on macOSX

Tags: c++, macos, openacc, pgi

my macOS is 10.12.4
and I have already installed the PGI on my macbook(just install by a setup program downloaded from PGI official website, activate its own console and no other operation, in this console, there have commands like "pgcc pgc++ and so on"), the version is 16.10
and I edit a test code with CLion:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _OPENACC
#include <openacc.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
#ifdef _OPENACC
    //part 1
    cout<<acc_get_num_devices(acc_device_not_host)<<endl;

    //part2
//    const int N = 1024;
//    //定义
//    int i, a[N], b[N], c[N];
//
//    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
//        c[i] = 0;
//        a[i] = b[i] = i;
//    }
//
//#pragma acc kernels
//    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
//        c[i] = b[i] + a[i];
//    }
//    std::cout << c[1] << std::endl;

#else
    cout << "not support OpenACC" << endl;

#endif

    return 0;
}
```

when I conpile it, I meet some problems:

```
MacBook13:TestOpenCV Chen$ pgc++ -acc -std=c++11 -Minfo main.cpp
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 93: error: pair is not a
          template
  template <class _T1, class _T2> struct __tuple_like<pair<_T1, _T2> > : true_type {};
                                                      ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 97: error: pair is not a
          template
  typename tuple_element<_Ip, pair<_T1, _T2> >::type&
                              ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 98: error: pair is not a
          template
  get(pair<_T1, _T2>&) _NOEXCEPT;
      ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 102: error: pair is not a
          template
  const typename tuple_element<_Ip, pair<_T1, _T2> >::type&
                                    ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 103: error: pair is not a
          template
  get(const pair<_T1, _T2>&) _NOEXCEPT;
            ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 108: error: pair is not a
          template
  typename tuple_element<_Ip, pair<_T1, _T2> >::type&&
                              ^

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
          /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple", line 109: error: pair is not a
          template
  get(pair<_T1, _T2>&&) _NOEXCEPT;
      ^

7 errors detected in the compilation of "main.cpp".
```

and no matter what part(part1 or part 2) to perform with pgc++,the error infomation is likely the same, and I don't know where I can start to resolve this problems, I am a new on macbook, really wish for your help~

Comment: I know nothing about the PGI compilers, hence just a comment (which may be grossly incorrect), but it seems to be looking at the Apple **Xcode** toolchain - which seems odd because if the PGI compiler is a compiler in its own right it would presumably have everything it needed. Personally, I would go to the **AppStore** and download Apple's **Xcode** and then run `xcode-select --install` to ensure I had all the dev/build tools you need from Apple then maybe reinstall or try the PGI compiler again.